# How to prevent users from logging in on their account on multiple android devices in android studio

Tags: android

I am working on an application that serves the users with some specific tasks. I want that when the user login then his mobile is registered like popular Banking apps are doing. After successful login, if the user again tries to log in to any other android he can not do that.

I searched a lot on google and found some results like to get IMEI, IMSI, etc. These are too old answers and now maybe google does not allow to get hardware-based ID from users.

Some answers lead me to ANDROID_ID and currently, I am using it but that's not working. Even when the user uninstalls the app this ID completely changed, and I need to delete the user record to log in again which is too headache. Sometimes ID changes sometimes not.

I want to know some way how I can achieve this. And any other way to get a nonchangeable ID?

Comment: use mac address of the device that won't change until and unless the user root their mobile.

Comment: @Zurmati according to google `Don't work with MAC addresses MAC addresses are globally unique, not user-resettable, and survive factory resets. For these reasons, it's generally not recommended to use MAC address for any form of user identification. Devices running Android 10 (API level 29) and higher report randomized MAC addresses to all apps that aren't device owner apps.`

Comment: then make a logic and assign a token to user and save that token in your server with, the token will only expire if the user gets logout, but lets suppose user's cell phone got lost and now he want to open account on new device then what will you do? You have to make logic by yourself to control this flow, I mean this thing totally depends on your business model.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadUsama

The ANDROID_ID will remain same if use same application identifier, same certificate to sign the app. 
So the best way is to use ANDROID_ID.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a boolean like 'isLoggedIn' field in your user table.
Your login API first checks this boolean, if its false then do the login work- else it would return 'already login'. For example:

```
  function login(username,password){
    if(!user.isLoggedIn){
       //all your logic
       isLoggedIn = true

    }else{
       return 'already logged in'
    }
  }
```

But for that you also need to have an API for logout process too. This will set this 'isLoggedIn' property as false. Called whenever user presses the logout button in the app.
The entire logic will reside at the backend rather than your android app. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: The issue is that if the user uninstalls the app without logout then this function fails.

Comment: As you mentioned that you want a process similar to the banking apps then you can also do what they are doing- their app expires the session timely and logs out the user.

Comment: When they log out the user, still user can not able to login account any other device. Only users can log in the same device.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but that doesn't seem right.